# Impossible to Remove FTDI driver / FTDI Enumeration on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, serial

I have already read the :

> [Is it possible to reset FTDI virtual com ports enumeration, we easily get hundreds of COM ports in production environment](https://superuser.com/questions/115172/is-it-possible-to-reset-ftdi-virtual-com-ports-enumeration-we-easily-get-hundred)

topics which was pretty interesting !

But I got a problem, apparently I can't delete the ftdi driver, so I can't use the previous conclusion of the topic... I'm really stuck and bored of this problem, my com port number is 132 !

Does someone have another solution ?

Answer (score 3):

i use the CDMuninstaller utility from this page:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "can't delete the driver"?  Have you tried uninstalling the unused virtual com ports as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/63830/serial-ports-com3-com49-used-but-not-listed-in-device-manager/63864#63864)?